Error en el archivo error_log de mi sitio en wordpress
Buen dia a todos, desde hace mucho tiempo navegando por los directorios de mi pagina del hosting y veo el archivo (error_log) que siempre sale el mismo mensaje de error y siempre lo paso borrando porque el archivo se llena con el mismo mensaje.
Les dejo el código de error que genera, por si alguien me puede decir el por qué sale, qué efectos negativos tiene y cómo puedo solucionarlo. Todos los plugins y temas estan actualizados.
Bueno, espero su ayuda. Gracias.
[12-Nov-2024 01:56:04 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'base_wp686.wp_posts' doesn't exist for query 
SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) AS `month`, 
    post_date AS post_date, count(ID) as count_posts
FROM wp_posts as posts
WHERE  post_type = 'post' 
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
    AND post_password = ''
    GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date)
    ORDER BY post_date DESC 
made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), 
require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), 
do_action('template_redirect'), 
WP_Hook->do_action, 
WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
GRIM_SG\Frontend->template_redirect, 
GRIM_SG\Sitemap->show_sitemap, 
GRIM_SG\Sitemap->generate_sitemap, 
GRIM_SG\Sitemap->collect_urls, 
GRIM_SG\Sitemap->add_archives, 
GRIM_SG\Vendor\QueryBuilder::run_query 


Esa consulta trae el archivo de posts por año y mes. ¿Cambiaste el prefix de las tablas en la configuración inicial de worpdress? wp_*. Si es así, corrige el plugin, tema o script que está tratando de leer la tabla incorrecta. ¿Qué tema estás usando? Es posible que el tema no esté usando la propiedad $wpdb->posts si no un valor fijado.

Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, el prefijo de las tablas no es wp_ bueno eso no entiendo muy bien de como cambiarlo seguramente el administrador del hosting cambio algo, pero si lo cambian el prefijo y poniendolo al wp_ se arreglara ese problema?? ahora si lo dejo asi que grave puede ser para mi pagina web, porque ahi veo que hace conflicto con el sitemap o no es grave el asunto, bueno espero tu ayuda gracias..

te está diciendo que la tabla base_wp686.wp_posts no existe. Te consta que el prefijo es  base_wp686 en tu instalación?

hola, el nombre de la base de datos es base_wp686 el prefijo de las tablas no es wp_ es este wpfd_ como solucionaria?, contacte con el hosting, me dijo que la base esta dañada y tiene que ser reparada y volver a instalar wordpress y solo se recupera los posts, imagenes lo demas plugins y themas tendria que configurar yo, hizo el proceso y desde que lo hizo mi web empeso a desaparecer de google y lo peor que ese mismo mensaje de error sigue saliendo en el archivo error_log no se arreglo nada, bueno a todo este problema que me esta pasando que solucion me recomiendan, gracias por sus respuestas.
